# Laravel 5.4 - How to change the Laravel log file name?

Tags: laravel-5.4, php-7

Laravel Version: 5.4.25
PHP Version: 7.0

In the previous versions of laravel there was a ConfigureLogging class to do this. But in the lastest version of laravel the class was deleted instead there is a new LogServiceProvider:

```
protected function configureDailyHandler(Application $app, Writer $log)
{

    $log->useDailyFiles(
        $app->storagePath() . '/logs/customLogName.log',
        $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5)
    );
}
```

I want to override this method.

How Can I do this ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try extending the LogServiceProvider and overriding the method

Comment: I have already tried that, but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've got it.

Add this in your `app/bootstrap/app.php` file after returning the `$app` instance:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) use ($app) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(
        (new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(
        // Set the log path
            $app->storagePath().'/logs/customLogName.log',
            // Set the number of daily files you want to keep
            $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5)
        ))->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true))
    );
});

return $app;
```

That do the trick

Comment: Very nice. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

This might have changed meanhwile, but currently (2020 with Laravel 7) there are less hacky ways to configure that, simply because in `config/logging.php` there are logging channels, eg. channel `daily` with the `daily` driver:

> **daily** - A `RotatingFileHandler` based `Monolog` driver which rotates daily.

One also can change the default logging channel in there (if desired):

```
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack')
```

---

And one can post directly to channels, eg. to one custom channel with the `daily` driver
(this channel produces a whole lot of spam, which I'd like to have isolated in a single file):

```
Log::channel('webhook')->debug($message);
```

---

Alike this one can organize the logging a whole lot better than just changing the output file name.

Answer (score -1):

For Laravel 5.5

In Path `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogServiceProvider.php`

Change function `configureDailyHandler`

line  `$this->app->storagePath().'/logs/laravel.log', $this->maxFiles(),`

to this

```
$this->app->storagePath().'/logs/laravel-'.get_current_user().'.log', $this->maxFiles(),
```

Or Just add this to your bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function (Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $filename = storage_path('logs/' . php_sapi_name() . '-' . posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'] . '.log');
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($filename, 30));
    $handler->setFilenameFormat('laravel-{date}-{filename}', 'Y-m-d');
    $formatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true);
    $formatter->includeStacktraces();
    $handler->setFormatter($formatter);
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't edit directly files from vendor directory.

Comment: The modification in `bootstrap/app.php` is the best choice. The vendor folder is in PSR pattern. If you try to update your composer packages you will create a big chance to get problems.